# Override typescript module exports definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have installed plugin that ship with types definition.

```
declare module 'autobind-decorator' {
  const autobind: ClassDecorator & MethodDecorator;
  export default autobind;
}
```

But, I thought that type definition was wrong. I need to change to this

```
declare module 'autobind-decorator' {
  const autobind: ClassDecorator & MethodDecorator;
  export = autobind;
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: 1) Why do you think that definition is wrong? 2) Contact the author/send a pull request…?

Comment: The types is wrong. The author is update the type in their repo but forgot to publish to NPM. https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator/commit/a716cbdf238166925d4dcf26a1bb3f9fd269bbfb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do that

Fork the project and publish (till the original gets fixed).

## More

This is essentially *if an author publishes a bad JS lib how do I fix it*. You would fix it by forking. TypeScript doesn't offer much magic here.

## Reason

If TypeScript offered a way to override it, it would lead to only confusion *which definition is used*.

Comment: Thanks, so far this is best answer I can accept well